# Create site collection using CSOM C# get error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, office365, sharepoint-online

I've made some code to create site collection via CSOM C# and the following code worked fine. But recently (1, 2 days back), it give me "ServerException Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source" and i cannot create any more site since then.

```
using (var tenantContext = new ClientContext("https://<Tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com"))
            {
                var password = ConvertToSecureString("my admin password");
                tenantContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("my admin account", password);

                var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);
                var siteCreationProperties = new SiteCreationProperties();

                siteCreationProperties.Title = "Site 01";
                siteCreationProperties.Url = "https://<Tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/site01";
                siteCreationProperties.Owner = "my admin account";

                var spo = tenant.CreateSite(siteCreationProperties);

                tenantContext.Load(spo, i => i.IsComplete);
                tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

And the Exception:

```
ex  {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"} System.Exception
```

{Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException}
Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult -2146233088 int
HelpLink    null    string
InnerException  null    System.Exception
Message "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"   string
ServerErrorCode -2147467261 int
ServerErrorDetails  null    object
ServerErrorTraceCorrelationId   "3a3ef99d-702c-3000-d2be-2391dc283133"  string
ServerErrorTypeName "System.ArgumentNullException"  string
ServerErrorValue    null    string
ServerStackTrace    ""  string
Source  "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime"   string
StackTrace  "   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()\r\n   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.CreateSite() in....\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 79"   string

Please help me to find out what is this Exception and how to resolve it.

Many Thanks and Best Regards,

David

Answer (score 0):

we had the same Issue yesterday and did a lot of research to investigate the error. But it was just that our Tenant had Issues. Try to start the site creation on a different Tenant and see if that works. Have also a look inside the Tenant "Admin Portal => Service health" if there are some problems with SharePoint.

Hope that save you some time.

Comment: Hi,
<br>
Thank you very much for you reply, i tried on a different Tenant and still got the error.
The Code seem fine so the problem i think it relates to other parts like Tenant as you say, the connection to Server, proxy...
Still investigating to find out what is the root cause.
<br>
Regards,
David

Comment: We are also getting same error in our tenant. I think there is a Global error by Microsoft.

Comment: Hi, /r/n
For more information:
- When i execute code at home with no proxy and free internet, everything worked fine, site created w/o any problem.
- But when i run code in company which has proxy, securities... kind of things, that Error appear again...

Comment: I have also seen this error in some tenants but not all.